# How to change the default box decoration to rounded rectangular box for ExpansionPanelList widget of Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Flutter's expansion panel list (https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/ExpansionPanelList-class.html) does not have a decoration. How to create a rounded edge expansion panel list? Please see the attached picture.

[image: image with problem description]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no direct way to make expansion panel corners rounded, but flutter being completely open source, you can easily get the implementation of ExpansionPanelList class and copy and make CustomExpansionPanelList to make UI as per your requirements. Here is simple code of CustomExpansionPanelList which you can use by simply replacing ExpansionPanelList widget with CustomExpansionPanelList

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const double _kPanelHeaderCollapsedHeight = 48.0;
const double _kPanelHeaderExpandedHeight = 64.0;

class CustomExpansionPanelList extends StatelessWidget {

  const CustomExpansionPanelList(
      {Key key,
      this.children: const <ExpansionPanel>[],
      this.expansionCallback,
      this.animationDuration: kThemeAnimationDuration})
      : assert(children != null),
        assert(animationDuration != null),
        super(key: key);

  final List<ExpansionPanel> children;

  final ExpansionPanelCallback expansionCallback;

  final Duration animationDuration;

  bool _isChildExpanded(int index) {
    return children[index].isExpanded;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final List<Widget> items = <Widget>[];
    const EdgeInsets kExpandedEdgeInsets = const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
        vertical: _kPanelHeaderExpandedHeight - _kPanelHeaderCollapsedHeight);

    for (int index = 0; index < children.length; index += 1) {
      if (_isChildExpanded(index) && index != 0 && !_isChildExpanded(index - 1))
        items.add(new Divider(
          key: new _SaltedKey<BuildContext, int>(context, index * 2 - 1),
          height: 15.0,
          color: Colors.transparent,
        ));

      final Row header = new Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          new Expanded(
            child: new AnimatedContainer(
              duration: animationDuration,
              curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
              margin: _isChildExpanded(index)
                  ? kExpandedEdgeInsets
                  : EdgeInsets.zero,
              child: new SizedBox(
                height: _kPanelHeaderCollapsedHeight,
                child: children[index].headerBuilder(
                  context,
                  children[index].isExpanded,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          new Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(end: 8.0),
            child: new ExpandIcon(
              isExpanded: _isChildExpanded(index),
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
              onPressed: (bool isExpanded) {
                if (expansionCallback != null)
                  expansionCallback(index, isExpanded);
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      );

      double _radiusValue = _isChildExpanded(index)? 8.0 : 0.0;
      items.add(
        new Container(
          key: new _SaltedKey<BuildContext, int>(context, index * 2),
          child: new Material(
            elevation: 2.0,
            borderRadius: new BorderRadius.all(new Radius.circular(_radiusValue)),
            child: new Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  header,
                  new AnimatedCrossFade(
                    firstChild: new Container(height: 0.0),
                    secondChild: children[index].body,
                    firstCurve:
                        const Interval(0.0, 0.6, curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn),
                    secondCurve:
                        const Interval(0.4, 1.0, curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn),
                    sizeCurve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
                    crossFadeState: _isChildExpanded(index)
                        ? CrossFadeState.showSecond
                        : CrossFadeState.showFirst,
                    duration: animationDuration,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
          ),
        ),
      );

      if (_isChildExpanded(index) && index != children.length - 1)
        items.add(new Divider(
          key: new _SaltedKey<BuildContext, int>(context, index * 2 + 1),
          height: 15.0,
        ));
    }

    return new Column(
      children: items,
    );
  }
}

class _SaltedKey<S, V> extends LocalKey {
  const _SaltedKey(this.salt, this.value);

  final S salt;
  final V value;

  @override
  bool operator ==(dynamic other) {
    if (other.runtimeType != runtimeType) return false;
    final _SaltedKey<S, V> typedOther = other;
    return salt == typedOther.salt && value == typedOther.value;
  }

  @override
  int get hashCode => hashValues(runtimeType, salt, value);

  @override
  String toString() {
    final String saltString = S == String ? '<\'$salt\'>' : '<$salt>';
    final String valueString = V == String ? '<\'$value\'>' : '<$value>';
    return '[$saltString $valueString]';
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Ganapat. I only made a small change i.e. commented elevation: 2.0 in the container.

Answer (score 3):

Wrap the ExpansionPanelList in a ClipRRect..

```
   return ClipRRect(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
      child: ExpansionPanelList(..)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

You can't. I copied the class ExpansionPanelList and make my own (CustomExpansionPanelList). Then I removed shadow and change color. I didn't find how can I add a border radius but I was able to make the same thing with Container and Border radius inside of them. The result looks pretty well:

[Border radius at ExpandedPanelList](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9Y2u.png)

Answer (score -3):

There is another easy way to achieve the same.

Set
elevation: 0

Comment: The question is about how to add a rounded corner to the expansion panel list, not about how to get rid of the shadow